# Angular JS ng-click does not work on search icon

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can someone please lead me into the right direction regarding my search icon? I need to make my search icon  clickable within the input field to display results.

Please see the following code listed below.

```
<div class="search-input">
   <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> <input
         placeholder="{{'SEARCH_HELP' | translate}}"
         type="text" class="input-sm form-control"
         ng-model="searchLocation" ng-enter="runUserSearch()" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `ng-click` ?

Comment: I was wondering with a ng-click <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" ng-click="runUserSearch()"></i>

Comment: @Hackerman <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" ng-click="runUserSearch()"></i>  I was thinking this would work but it doesn't

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/9xhejpze/3/

Comment: @Hackerman  I was able to get it to work. I had a ruling in my css preventing events.

Comment: I know it, if my test code works then it should be something else xD

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-click instead of ng-enter

```
<div class="search-input">
   <div class="inner-addon right-addon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> <input
         placeholder="{{'SEARCH_HELP' | translate}}"
         type="text" class="input-sm form-control"
         ng-model="searchLocation" ng-click="runUserSearch()" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Salih, this actually makes the entire input field clickable. I only need the search icon to be  clickable.